# Prove that every embedded submanifold is naturally a manifold

Tags: manifolds

it's my first question, I know it's easy but I just dont know how to write this demonstration, any help is welcome, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please edit your question to include your own thoughts/attempts so people will have a better sense of how to assist you.

Comment: Just another example of how to frighten people away.

Answer (score 2):

$\textbf{Hint}$

In order to find charts for the submanifold try to use the embedding and the charts of the ambient manifold...

Comment: This hint could be misleading as *ambient* could be interpreted as the immersion's codomain. To produce a chart for the embedded submanifold one has to use a chart from the domain of the immersion map.